# Area of a rectangle foolproof

Tags: c, foolproof-validation

Who can help me with the area of ​​a rectangle. I can't make foolproof, ie the ban on entering letters and negative numbers.I just can not create a second condition when creating the first that refers to the letters. How can I do this, or I must even change the program from scratch. I just need to find the area of ​​a rectangle.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <Windows.h>

int _tmain(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    printf("Area of a Rectangle. Press Enter to start\n");
    system("pause");

    float a, s, d;

    do
    {
        fflush(stdin);
        system("cls");
        printf("Enter the lengths of the rectangle\n");
        scanf_s("%f", &a);
        scanf_s("%f", &s);

        if (getchar() != '\n') {
            while (getchar() != '\n')
                ;
            printf("Your data is wrong\n");
            system("pause");
            continue;
        }

        break;
    } while (true);

    d = a*s;
    printf(" Area is %.1f ", d);
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: the statement: `fflush(stdin)` is explicitly stated in the C standard to not work.  That is because 'fflush()` is only for output streams, not input streams.   suggest using: `while( int ch = getchar() && ch != EOF && ch != '\n');`

Comment: the variable names: 'a' 's' and 'd' are meaningless.  Your code should always use meaningful names for variables other than index/loop counter variables.   Suggest:  rectHeight rectWidth rectArea.

Comment: this line: `printf("Enter the lengths of the rectangle\n");` doesn't really tell the user what to enter.  suggest: `printf("Enter length width of a rectangle\n");`   Always check the returned value from a call to the scanf() family of functions to assure the operation was successful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This program will ask for a numeric value and accept only positive values. An input of letters or symbols will cause `scanf()` to fail and the program will clear the input buffer and try again.  In this example, inputting the letter 'q' will quit the program. You could adapt this to your situation.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>


int main()
{
    int i = 0;
    float n = 0.0f;

    do {
        printf("enter numeric value or q to quit\n");
        if ( scanf("%f",&n) != 1) {// scan one float
            while ( ( i = getchar ( )) != '\n' && i != 'q') {
                //clear buffer on scanf failure
                //stop on newline
                //quit if a q is found
            }
            if ( i != 'q') {
                printf ( "problem with input, try again\n");
            }
        }
        else {//scanf success
            if ( n == fabs ( n)) {
                printf("number was %f\n", n);
            }
            else {
                printf("positive numbers only please\n");
            }
        }
    } while ( i != 'q');

    return 0;
}
```

This has adapted the above into a function.

```
#include <stdio.h>

float getfloat ( char *prompt, int *result);

int main ( int argc, char* argv[])
{
    float width, height, area;
    int ok = 0;

    do {
        printf("\n\tArea of a Rectangle.\n");
        width = getfloat ( "Enter the width of the rectangle or q to quit\n", &ok);
        if ( ok == -1) {
            break;
        }
        height = getfloat ( "Enter the height of the rectangle or q to quit\n", &ok);
        if ( ok == -1) {
            break;
        }

        area = width * height;
        printf(" Area is %.1f\n", area);
    } while (1);

    return 0;
}

float getfloat ( char *prompt, int *result)
{
    int i = 0;
    float n = 0.0f;

    *result = 0;

    do {
        printf("%s", prompt);
        if ( scanf("%f",&n) != 1) {// scan one float
            while ( ( i = getchar ( )) != '\n' && i != 'q') {
                //clear buffer on scanf failure
                //stop on newline
                //quit if a q is found
            }
            if ( i != 'q') {
                printf ( "problem with input, try again\n");
            }
            else {
                *result = -1;
                n = 0.0f;
            }
        }
        else {//scanf success
            if ( n == fabs ( n)) {
                *result = 1;
            }
            else {
                printf("positive numbers only please\n");
            }
        }
    } while ( *result == 0);

    return n;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, for your feedback

Answer (score 1):

A foolproof `scanf` for a float will look like this

```
float getFloat() {
    float in;
    while(scanf("%f", &in) != 1 && getchar() != '\n') {
        fflush(stdin);
        fprintf(stderr, "Wrong input, enter again : ");
    }
    return in;
}
```

This works for me. Your code will then simplify to

```
float a = getFloat();
float b = getFloat();
printf("Area is %.1f", a * b);
```